# Does anyone know how to use health-upgrades that we get as rewards?

Tags: tomb-raider-guardian

I'm currently playing **Tomb Raider - Guardian of Light**. In the game we receive health-upgrades and ammo-upgrades as rewards. Now there are two ways this can happen:

**1. Lara reaches a difficult-to-reach place and finally gets the pick-up reward.** Here the result is instantaneous. We can immediately see the health bar increase.
 **2. Lara completes a level bonus objective** (like enter spider tomb in 5 minutes or collect 10 skulls in the level) and the health-upgrade seems to be added to the inventory.

**The question is, for step 2, how do we use that health-upgrade**? 

The upgrade remains in inventory and nothing happens when we click it. I thought the upgrade was automatically applied after the level. But in the next level I see my health-bar exactly the same as previous level end.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The health and ammo bar actually increase *immediately* on completing an objective.

For example you need to complete a trap in 1 minute and you'll get a reward of a health upgrade.

- The second you complete it you health bar increases instantly. If you are new to the game you would probably be concentrating on the puzzle rather than the health bar.
- There is no animation highlighting that your health *increased*. The bar increases instantly *and then* there is animation that just highlight the health bar (we should be highlighting the increase not only the bar).
- The increments themselves are quite little which again makes it easy for beginners to miss noticing them.
- Combine this with the fact that the upgrades exist in your inventory screen. I'm more used to the idea that if its in my inventory I can use it. If the health upgrade has already been applied it makes more sense to me to not have them as part of what appears to be a kind of inventory screen.

Due to these points I was confused for sometime about the upgrades. Now just because I mentioned the points above doesn't mean I don't like the game. I'm merely answering my question. Also, Tomb Raider series have always been a good and I still continue to replay 
some games.

Hope this helps all who are new to the game. Happy gaming!